# Permissions issues running fcgi

Tags: apache, cpanel, fastcgi

I am running Apache and fcgi for the php interpreter, but I keep running into permissions issues when a cms creates a file or a plugin is uploaded. What is the way around this? Also, the server is running cpanel. I have root access too.

Answer (score 0):

Check who is owner of directory and permissions. 
Upload directory should have 0700 if you are owner, 0770 if you are in group or 0777 if process owner is in others.

The best solution is to reduce unnecessary access. Check who is owner of PHP FCGI server and give it permissions by changing ownership.

**Edit1:**

You can change permissions by typing in console

```
chmod 0777 /.../path_to_directory
```

Or do It by CPanel file manager. There is a gold key icon with "Change permission" label. If you have no experience, just change it to 0777.

Comment: The owner is 501, how would I give it permission, I haven't done this before.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that is permanent, where I don't have to change the permissions every time that I install a plugin. Is this possible?

Comment: Whatever script will create inside, will have same access mode (I'm not sure but it's probably default behavior). Don't worry. You will have to change permissions only once.